# Ubuntu 20.04 packages missing all mo-files in docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, deb

For some reason, iso-codes package does not install it's files inside docker image.

Here is what as consider more or less minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iso-codes
RUN ls /usr
```

I have left locale-related settings in case those are relevant. The same problem appears when I comment all but `FROM` and `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iso-codes` out.

Building:

```
docker build -t 'mytry:1' .
```

Now when I run the following, I do not see anything in the directory where mo-files should reside:

```
docker run --cidfile /tmp/docker_test.cid 'mytry:1' ls -R /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/
```

However, `dpkg -l` shows it's there:

```
ii  iso-codes               4.4-1                        all          ISO language, territory, currency, script codes and their translations
```

And `dpkg -L` has some files in the directory:

```
/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/iso_3166-2.mo
/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/iso_3166_2.mo
```

What is that I am missing? (I am using the specific docker run way just for simplicity. The same problem arises in the normal usage)

I also tried `find / -name 'iso_3166-1.mo'`, but seems like there is no such file anywhere.

Also it seems like poedit-common, which also should have mo files, is missing them, so the problem is more general.

`docker -v` gives

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found the reason:

```
cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes
# Drop all man pages
path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*

# Drop all translations
path-exclude=/usr/share/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo

# Drop all documentation ...
path-exclude=/usr/share/doc/*

# ... except copyright files ...
path-include=/usr/share/doc/*/copyright

# ... and Debian changelogs
path-include=/usr/share/doc/*/changelog.Debian.*
```

In order to get locales, one should comment out the `path-exclude` line for `/usr/share/locale/...`  or replace the file. Before installing packages.

Of course, the size of the image can grow as a result.